# How can I change font background of email text in thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I would like to add background color for several words in my email. If I try to use background color option Thunderbird adds background to the whole email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the extension that can do this - Highlighter: https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/thunderbird/addon/highlighter-222207/

One more way without extension usage: Click Insert – HTML while message composing and insert

```
<span style="background-color: yellow;">word or phrase</span>
```